# Flutter: Undefined name 'AppLocalizations'. Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name

Tags: flutter, localization, flutter-getx, flutter-localizations, applocalizations

Flutter Default Localizations isn't work when I use GetX Statemanagement. It show me a error like

```
Undefined name 'AppLocalizations'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.
```

[image]

**How Can I fixed this ?**

Answer (score 3):

Please add these dependencies on pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.17.0
```

More information [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization)

Answer (score 2):

for me the problem solved by

This creates a pubspec.yml file with the following entries:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: any
```

then  `pub get`

Answer (score 1):

Add it in dependency
->    generate:true;

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in a Flutter widget test code. The solution illustrated by the images below is applicable to the Flutter app code as well. Note that my Flutter app is conform to the MVVM architecture using Provider, the reason why MultiProvider is used. The code of the project is available on GitHub [My AudioLearn prototype project](https://github.com/Archanciel/chatgpt_audio_learn). Note that the real project will be referenced in the readme file and will available as well since earning money is not what motivates me to develop this application.

[image: Solution in widget test code 1]

[image: Solution in widget test code 2]

[image: Solution in widget test code 3]

[image: Solution in widget test code 4]